# Does elementary intend to take any action regarding the use of flutter, as well as ubuntu?

Tags: microsoft-windows, ubuntu

Ubuntu published on its twitter [Flutter is the default choice for future @ubuntu apps.](https://twitter.com/FlutterDev/status/1367173897456480258) about standardizing its future applications with the flutter. It seems to me a good choice, since microsoft also intends to optimize windows for development with flutter [Microsoft is continuing to expand its support for Flutter.](https://developers.googleblog.com/2021/03/announcing-flutter-2.html). I want to know if there will be any action or case study regarding the use of flutter by default in elementary os.

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, you may want to ask this type of question in one of their GitHub repos, perhaps the 'os' section. https://github.com/elementary

Answer (score 1):

It's unlikely to happen anytime soon.
Flutter is still a very young framework and elementary focuses on stability.
Since elementary already has a blessed toolchain, Vala, I'm not sure why they would do this.
Changing this would force developers who have already invested in Vala to learn Flutter and Dart and that seems like a lot to ask.
It seems that apps built for elementary are supposed to be built specifically for elementary and *not* cross-platform.